# How to execute Jenkinsfile with gerrit trigger plugin for changeset in jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

We use gerrit-trigger in Jenkins, the build is triggered when a new changeset is pushed for review.

Now we want to introduce pipeline and use solution [Defining a pipeline in scm](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#defining-a-pipeline-in-scm)

Therefore we expect when the build is triggered, below pipeline plugin can work to checkout this refspec

[image]

But the `${GERRIT_REFSPEC}` doesn't effect here, it checkouts the master still

```
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision adf5d360582b1b24f088cfa8ac0f0ebf64a57692 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
Commit message: "DO:CI End of summer"
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f adf5d360582b1b24f088cfa8ac0f0ebf64a57692
```

Any suggestion how it can work?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you need to set:

```
Repositories > Refspec               = $GERRIT_REFSPEC:$GERRIT_REFSPEC
Branches to build > Branch Specifier = $GERRIT_REFSPEC
```

Important: do not forget to uncheck the "***Lightweight checkout***" option.

Comment: Thx, but no, I got error `stderr: fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/$GERRIT_REFSPEC`, the git plugin here is used under pipeline configuration, the variable is not available.

Comment: I was able to reproduce your issue and added more info.

Comment: Unbelievable !!, it works, can you give me reference why it works?

Comment: The "Lightweight checkout" is a special mode to improve efficiency. Click on the "?" and see that "build parameters will not be substituted into SCM configuration in this mode".

Comment: I didn't quite get that answer until I clicked on that "Advanced" button, which reveal the Refspec field. It works! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use in Jenkins job.

Refspec: ${GERRIT_REFSPEC}

Branch Specifier: FETCH_HEAD.

Answer (score -2):

uncheck “Lightweight checkout” is enough!!
gerrit-trigger plugin should mention this!
it wasted my half day!